# VS2012: manifest authoring error c1010005: The root element name should be <assembly/>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, uac

I took the manifest file from the Microsoft documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742884.aspx
It does not work!

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:0073chemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
        <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
            level="highestAvailable"
            UIAccess="true" />
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
</trustInfo>
```

Manifest authoring error c1010005: The root element name should be `<assembly/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a complete manifest, just a snippet. You can [find one here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19346512/17034).

Btw, there's no need to do this by hand at all in VS2012.  It already supports auto-generating the manifest.  Right-click your project, Properties, Linker, Manifest File.  Change the UAC Execution Level setting to "highestAvailable".

Comment: What did 'UIAccess' do again? And why does setting it to 'true' give me an error about a server connection?

Comment: Type "uiaccess and manifest" in the Search box to refresh your memory.